# Restricted permission

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, permissions, designer-workflow

I have created a list which has a a column to choose different groups. I would like to retrict the permission for it. Suppose a HR guy logs in he should be able to view only the items updated by users in HR group. Same goes with Sales and IT. Can anybody tell me the procedure to do it from out of Box or through sharepoint designer. Its bit urgent...

Comment: You want to restrict permissions at column level or item level?

Comment: Item level.. but there is a column which gives you the option of selecting the group while adding an item in the list. Once he has added, he can just find the items under HR.

Comment: So you can user Sharepoint designer workflows to set permissions for the user.

Comment: Can you please explain more how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add a condition like below in your Query in the SP view.
It basically checks whether the current logged in user is part of a group which is specified in a particular column.

```
<Membership Type=\"CurrentUserGroups\">

       <FieldRef Name=\"ColumnName\"/>

     </Membership>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. is there a way to do it from sharepoint designer or may be through workflows?

Comment: @user29507 open designer . goto the list. open the allitems or whatever view you want to edit. Add this to the caml query inside that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use folders option in the list and access can be restricted to that

Comment: Ok...but while adding a new item how will the item pertaining to HR, will fall in the HR folder? Actually I have customised the list in infopath. User will receive a link to the infopath form which he will fill in and this will get updated in list and when he goes back to list, he should be able to view just his group items.